# Scatter matplotlib градиент

Tags: python, matplotlib

Помогите пожалуйста поставить градиент от голубого к красному

Вот мой код

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KkbT7gwmVVHLBIRlxudwN08UKuIBoijG/view?usp=sharing"
file_path = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file_url.split('/')[-2]
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

data=data[95000:]

plt.figure(figsize =(30, 10))
plt.scatter(data['Formatted Date'], data['Temperature (C)'],cmap='jet',s=50,alpha = 0.8)
plt.grid(color = '#33ccff', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)
plt.xticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: cmap почему-то не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вы не задали значения для цвета, поэтому палитру у вас не к чему применять. Предположу, что цвета вы хотите тоже согласно столбцу температуры задать, хотя там может быть и любой другой столбец:

```py
plt.scatter(data['Formatted Date'], data['Temperature (C)'],
            c=data['Temperature (C)'], cmap='jet', s=50, alpha = 0.8)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]